# dynamically create HTML divisions based on local storage data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, local-storage

I've the following JSON in my local storage.

```
userData:[{
           "name":"John",
           "dob":"2011-02-01",
           "gender":"male",
           "marital_status":"married",
           "email":"john@gmail.com"
          },
          {
           "name":"Paul",
           "dob":"2011-08-05",
           "gender":"male",
           "marital_status":"unmarried",
           "email":"paul@gmail.com"
          },
          {
           "name":"Mary",
           "dob":"2011-12-11",
           "gender":"female",
           "marital_status":"married",
           "email":"mary@gmail.com"
          }]
```

In the above JSON I've 3 users namely:John,Paul and Mary within an array 'userData' in my local storage. The number of users can be >3 or <3,
How can I create HTML divs(which has user icon with a delete button) based on number of users present at any given point of time. I'm also performing delete user operation and hence it has to be dynamic in nature. I'm trying to achieve this with jquery, but found nothing useful. I have so far tried to count the array elements and based on that I'm showing or hiding divs which are already coded in my HTML(for 4 users scenario)

```
if(counter==4)
  {
    $("#avatar1").show();
    $("#avatar2").show();
    $("#avatar3").show();
    $("#avatar4").show();
}
  else if(counter==3)
  {
    $("#avatar1").show();
    $("#avatar2").show();
    $("#avatar3").show();
    $("#avatar4").hide();
  }
  else if(counter==2)
  {
    $("#avatar1").show();
    $("#avatar2").show();
    $("#avatar3").hide();
    $("#avatar4").hide();
  }
  else if(counter==1)
  {
    $("#avatar1").show();
    $("#avatar2").hide();
    $("#avatar3").hide();
    $("#avatar4").hide();
  }
  else{
  $("#container").html("<p>No Users found</p>");
  }
```

where, counter=number of elements in the array (userData in this case).
Is there any way to do it dynamically or Am I totally wrong making no sense? I don't think it is impossible, but I'm just trying to complete the task searching for solutions.

Comment: Do you mind using a for loop?

Comment: No, I don't. But I just want to make sure if I'm towards the right approach of showing/hiding divs. I felt like it was just faking users. It is a real time project and hence I want my code to be of good quality. If this way of approach iis right, then I'll proceed further.Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically show the data load the json and loop through the element and append to the html document. An example is in the link the link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/princedc/qwb2ubqx/1/

Assume you have div tag with id "userNames" as below

```
<div id="userNames">
</div>
```

you can load the json and loop through it to create dynamic page element and append to the above div. This will cater to any number of dynamic data in the json.

```
var jsonData = { userData:[{
           "name":"John",
           "dob":"2011-02-01",
           "gender":"male",
           "marital_status":"married",
           "email":"john@gmail.com"
          },
          {
           "name":"Paul",
           "dob":"2011-08-05",
           "gender":"male",
           "marital_status":"unmarried",
           "email":"paul@gmail.com"
          },
          {
           "name":"Mary",
           "dob":"2011-12-11",
           "gender":"female",
           "marital_status":"married",
           "email":"mary@gmail.com"
          }]
          };

(function (){ 
    for(var i=0; i < jsonData.userData.length;i++){
       $('#userNames').append('<div>'+ jsonData.userData[i].name + '</div>');
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks nanba! Working fine.. Helped me proceeding further. Super ji

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try this:

```
function ShowAvatars(number) {
    var counter = 1;
    if (number === 0) {
        $("#container").html("<p>No Users found</p>");
    } else {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            if (counter <= number) {
                $("#avatar" + i).show();
            } else {
                $("#avatar" + i).hide();
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does the job but I require things to happen dynamically. avatar+i can go even upto 50 or more. (I just tried with 4 users) It is not possible to keep 50 divs ready in my HTML for this purpose. Anyway, this sinppet helped me in moving further towards the progress. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does everything that you want.

Creates a user avatar with their name next to it and a button.

```
data.forEach((user) => {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.classList.add('row');

        var outerpanel = document.createElement('div');
        outerpanel.classList.add('panel');
        outerpanel.classList.add('panel-default');
        outerpanel.style.marginTop = '5%';

        var panelbody = document.createElement('div');
        panelbody.classList.add('panel-body');

        var innerpanel = document.createElement('div');
        innerpanel.classList.add('row');
        innerpanel.innerHTML = `
            <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png" height="50px" width="100px"/>
            <div style="vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold;">
              ${user.name}
            </div>
            <div class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" style="vertical-align:middle; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; line-height:25px;"> X </div>
        `;

        panelbody.append(innerpanel);
        outerpanel.append(panelbody);
        row.append(outerpanel);

        document.getElementById('user-container').append(outerpanel);
      });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/P0asYI7fSHqDjeq4ymK9?p=preview

Comment: This example uses bootstrap for styling.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use bootstrap, sorry for not mentioning :D Anyway this helped me a lot. I can steal some code out of this for sure! Thanks for your time.